# GCE Project with Pending Deletion

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have had several projects on Pending deletion for several months and they are not being removed from the console. Any idea why this is occurring?

Answer (score 1):

I too have a few projects that have been pending deletion for a few months now.

According to [this Google document](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#creatingdeletingprojects) "the time it takes to delete a project might vary depending on the number or kind of services in use within the project.", so it may take an indeterminate amount of time.

Comment: I have gone through those docs as well and I can't seem to find anything that is holding up the deletion process. Thanks anyway

Comment: Wow.  Another small snippet from the same doc:  "For example, if a project has billing set up, it may not be completely deleted until the current billing cycle ends, you receive the next bill, and your account is successfully charged."  A very relevant question:  when do they stop accumulating charges, at the time of deletion or the end of the billing cycle?